# How do you load a string from local file only using client-side languages?

Tags: javascript, html, object, local-storage, client-side

I would like to load some text from either a text file or (preferably) a comma-separated value file. The web application is a single HTML file on a shared drive (due to business restrictions of data protection). The text file will be in the same directory as the HTML file.

I need a method of getting the data into the web app automatically on start up, this would simplify the interactions with the application, yet still make it easy enough to add more data the system for end users.

I have tried using objects which have been able to get the text loaded into the body but it loads up a new document of which I do not know how to manipulate in Javascript.

Comment: show us what you have so far, I'm sure we'll be able to help you

Comment: have you tried using the onload method? <body onload="c()" then you just need to figure out how to load the file with JavaScript.

Comment: You can't access the local file-system in a regular browser but with HTML Applications in Windows you can use either AJAX or the Scripting.FileSystemObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might this be to your help?

```
    function fetchAllShortStock()
{
    $.get("shortStock.txt", function(data) { <-- loads the file with jQuery


    var mydata = data.split("\n"); <-- Splits the loaded text on each new line.
    var allShortStock;



    for(var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++)
    {
        allShortStock.append('"')
        var shortStock = mydata[i];
        allShortStock.append(shortStock);

    }
```